# Minimum covering radius in n dimensions

Tags: algorithm, axis, geometry, cover

Is there any known algorithm to solve this ?

Comment: Of course there is some kind of an algorithm you could use. What kind of time complexity are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is asking for an algorithm, not help with broken code

Comment: Are the centers also integers, or could they be halves?

Answer (score 1):

There's a related problem that's solvable with a greedy algorithm: given the points and a *radius*, find the minimum number of *circles*. This algorithm repeatedly places a circle whose left edge lies on the leftmost uncovered point, running in time O(n) on points sorted by x.

To get an algorithm for the requested problem, sort the points once and then use binary search to find the least radius that will result in at most d circles. Assuming that the x coordinates can be represented by machine words, this should be fine. (If not, there are other algorithms.)

Comment: @Blender He is suggesting you to use binary search on answer and I agree with him. Similar to this questions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189551/arrange-n-items-in-k-nonempty-groups-such-that-the-difference-between-the-minimu/40205972#40205972) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673898/divide-array-into-k-contiguos-partitions-such-that-sum-of-maximum-partition-is-m/39675098#39675098)